# Excel 2013 shortcut to change font size

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I am using Excel 2013 (32bit)

The shortcut of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> OR <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> are not working. These now give me the effect of copy down or copy right.

Does anyone know of anyother shortcut, apart from the ribbon shortcuts?

Comment: Not according to the periodic table: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/christmas-gifts-for-excel-nerds/   :(

Comment: I'm sorry @CLockeWork, my comment was poor. It should have been : Firee, if you don't mind paying, you can use http://www.veodin.com/excel-2013-shortcuts/ and then use CTRL + SHIFT + F or CTRL + SHIFT + G

Comment: @DaveRook The  Ctrl+[ and Ctrl+] does not work. It gives an error msg, "No cells were found"

Comment: Also, I can always record a macro to assign the shortcut for that function. I was curious, if any default shortcut existed.

Answer (score 3):

I've searched and experimented and it looks like this feature is not available in 2013 (see comments below)

I'm still hoping that there's an actual answer to this, but in the meantime I've put together a very rough macro to emulate the effect you're after (whether it's of use to you or to future readers).

At the moment this makes any selected range of cells bigger or smaller by one pt, but only if all cells are currently the same size.

You'll need to paste this into a module

--If you or anyone else doesn't know how to do this:

1. Go to the Developer tab (you may need to add this to your Ribbon in
   settings)
2. Click on Visual Basic
3. Expand the current work book in the VB window
4. Right-click on Modules
5. Click Insert>Insert Module

```
Sub MakeBigger()
'
'Makes selected cells' fonts bigger by one pt, 
'  only works if all selected cells have the same font size
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
    Selection.Font.Size = Selection.Font.Size + 1

End Sub

Sub MakeSmaller()
'
'Makes selected cells' fonts smaller by one pt, 
'  only works if all selected cells have the same font size
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'

    Selection.Font.Size = Selection.Font.Size - 1


End Sub
```

Then go to Developer>Macros and Select each macro, pressing Options and adding the keyboard shortcuts there

Comment: Thanks.. But I can always record a macro to that effect.. CTRL+W I use regularly to close workbooks... Does the CTRL+SHIFT+> function work for others in Excel 2013, or is it a bug in my system... I know it works like a dream in powerpoint 2013

Comment: No worries, though recording alone just sets a fixed font size so you will need something to this effect (the keyboard shortcut is just a suggestion.) I've tried every shortcut I can think of (and made up a bunch) with no luck. Ctrl+Shift+> or < is deleting the selected cell for me (2013)

Comment: Looks like Ctrl+Shift+> either deletes or does something arcane that deletes in the process. Ctrl+Shift+] or [ now selects formula descendants and precedents. The only thing I can find that does what you want is part of the product that Dave Rook suggested, which costs £79. If they’re charging that much when increase or decrease font is one of their only exclusive shortcuts then I’m thinking it must have been removed from the Excel defaults.

Comment: It doesn't make sense actually for microsoft to delete this basic shortcut from excel, because it works in Word as well as Powerpoint

Comment: That's exactly what I'm thinking. They do something different in Excel, obviously something they felt was more important, but I fail to see why :(

Answer (score 0):

Type Alt H FK on the cell for which you want to decrease the font size & 
 Alt H FG to increase the font size

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i was not looking for a generic shortcut and not the ribbon ones